# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src' while importing logging

Tags: python, logging, jupyter-notebook, module, src

I'm working on one one Python project and facing this error while importing logging in research.ipynb file.
[Here my github link which direct open logger.py file](https://github.com/Harsh-Kamani/fsdML_project/blob/master/src/DimondPricePrediction/logger.py).
Now You can navigate to research.ipynb file which is "fsdML_project\notebooks\research.ipynb". Check the last cell.